# Curved line draw in HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, line

I want to draw a curve like [this mentioned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtJeF.png) in HTML5 canvas. 
Can someone point to what methods should I use.?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Tried quadraticCurveTo but seems to be it takes a certain shape only.

Comment: what about bezierCurveTo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yet an other way of doing it is using [the method bezierCurveTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 536;
let ch = canvas.height = 100;
   
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0,28)
ctx.bezierCurveTo(0,28,31,7,70,8);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(109,9,313,99,425,90);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(516,82.5,536,55,536,55);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid #d9d9d9;}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that looks roughly like `-sin`, so you could do something like:

```js
let cnvs = document.getElementById('cnvs')
let ctx = cnvs.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
for (let i = 0; i < cnvs.width; i++){
    ctx.lineTo(i, cnvs.height/2-Math.sin(i*(Math.PI/180))*50);
}
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas id='cnvs'></canvas>
```

So the idea their is to express your curve as some function of `x` (here it is `-sin(x)`) and then use the rendering context's `lineTo` method to draw lines between different points on that curve. So long as you increment over every few pixels (here `1` is as good as it gets), then you will have the effect of a nice smooth graph.