# Drawing a spider web in processing starting from a vectorial file

Tags: java, processing

Hello awesome community,
for a university project i need to create a **spider web** in **processing** that builds itself when **"mousepressed"**, *the more you hold the click, the more the spider web expands*. When the click is released the web just stop expanding.
I'm a beginner in coding and i started learning in the last few weeks.
Does anybody have any idea of how could i make it? **There is a reference in the image atached below.**
I was thinking about using a vectorial file made in illustrator (maybe) that just build his stroke as long as mouse is pressed, but i don't know if this is even possible. Does anyone have some tips about how could i make it?
Thank you all for the answers. Love

[image: spider web]

Comment: If this is a school project chances are that the class material should give you an idea of how to start, right? Your teacher probably showed some techniques which they believe would allow you to come up with a solution for this homework they decided to give. So your best bet is probably to get back to these techniques, try to do a first implementation and ask a question here when you have some code to demonstrate and a precise problem to ask about. Otherwise it's likely you will not get quality answers because people don't want to think about your homework for you.

Comment: It is a university project where we decide what to do and bring it to the final exam, considering that the next year i will take the media interaction course i'm trying to learn by myself something about generative art, processing and p5.js. There was probably a misunderstanding in my question, sorry about that, but i was trying to find out a way to do it and understanding how i should proceed, what technique to use ecc. I didn't want anyone to write the entire code, of course.

Comment: Why is this tagged with java and p5.js? You're doing it in Javascript or Java?

Comment: if you're using js you probably need only need to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52484109/curved-line-draw-in-html5-canvas) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634460/quadratic-b%C3%A9zier-curve-calculate-points). If you're going to use java instead of the first one use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562992/java-swing-drawing-curved-lines). Do some code and then comeback if you need help in something in specific.