# Ways to make bezier curves with about 8-9 control points in Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-development, bezier

I am making a game where i need to display ship traversing a flowing river. I am creating river with bezier curves but it is with only 3 control points from the [bezerCurveTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo). So, the river is not 'curvy enough.' How can i go about achieving this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bezier-curve

Comment: If you’re using this API, then all Bézier curves are going to be cubic. You need to string together multiple Bézier curves. If the river is going to be static, then it may be helpful to draw it in a vector graphics application first, then take the resulting SVG path and translate it into Canvas API calls.

Comment: Maybe this is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52486160/5246900
Probably duplicate question.

Comment: Use a spline instead

Comment: @Bergi Canvas has no API functions for splines, as far as I know?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding how to effect "curviness" in that case: just because your shape needs more bends than a single cubic curve offers, doesn't mean you can't just use _multiple curves_ in the same way we use multiple lines to form a polygon. Use a series of `bezierCurveTo` instructions instead of a single one and you can make your river as bendy as you like.

Answer (score 0):

The tabageos.GeometricMath Class has some advanced functions for curves, paths and merging Arrays. To accomplish what you want you could join multiple paths together. For example: https://codepen.io/Contrapenner/pen/mdBVrbw

```
function dot(x, y) {
    var d = document.createElement("span");
    d.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;left:" + x + "px;top:" + y + "px;width:2px;height:2px;background: blue");
    document.getElementById("river").appendChild(d);
  };
  var riverPath = tabageos.GeometricMath.getRawArcCurvePath(5, 5, 10, 10, 5, 15, 10);
  riverPath = tabageos.GeometricMath.mergeArrays(riverPath, tabageos.GeometricMath.getRawArcCurvePath(5, 15, 0, 20, 5, 25, 10));
  riverPath = tabageos.GeometricMath.mergeArrays(riverPath, tabageos.GeometricMath.getRawArcCurvePath(5, 25, 10, 30, 5, 35, 10));
  riverPath = tabageos.GeometricMath.mergeArrays(riverPath, tabageos.GeometricMath.getRawArcCurvePath(5, 35, 0, 40, 5, 45, 10));
  //and you could keep going as needed.
  //there is also getRawHermiteCurvePath
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < riverPath.length; i += 2) {
    dot(riverPath[i], riverPath[i + 1]);
  }
```